# Reference to a variable depending on a conditional

Tags: scheme, lisp

We can choose an operator depending on a condition:

```
(let ((x 10))
    (display ((if (< 0 1) - +) x))
    (newline)
)
; output -10
```

Can we do the same with variables?

```
(let ((x 0) (y 0))
    (set! (if (< 0 1) x y) 1) ; evaluate a reference to a variable, not his value
    (display x) (newline)
    (display y) (newline)
)
```

if condition is true set `x` to 1, set `y` to 1 otherwise.

I mean without repeating the `set!` function, I know that it can be solved using:

```
(let ((x 0) (y 0))
    (if (< 0 1)
        (set! x 1)
        (set! y 1)
    )
    (display x) (newline)
    (display y) (newline)
)
```

The intention is to clean this piece of code:

```
(define-macro (inc x n)
    `(set! ,x (+ ,x ,n))
)
define hmap (make-hash-table 50))
(hashq-set! hmap 'foo "bar")
(hashq-set! hmap 'bar "foo")
(hashq-set! hmap 'baz 42)
(let ((n 0) (n-strings 0) (n-numbers 0))
    (hash-fold
        (lambda (key value seed)
            (inc n 1)
            (if (string? value)
                (inc n-strings 1)
                (if (number? value)
                    (inc n-numbers 1)
                )
            )
        )
        0 hmap
    )
    (format #t "The map contains ~a elements: ~a are strings and ~a are numbers\n"
        n n-strings n-numbers
    )
)
```

How can it be implemented in a more elegant way?

Comment: it will be false elegance. just re-write your nested ifs as a cond. it's better not to be able to write brittle convoluted hard-to-change code. the goal is for a code to be self-evidently correct. for that it must be clear, simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can, but `set!` won't.  I am not sure the following macro is completely correct, but I think it may be.  I've only tested it in Racket though.

```
(define-syntax st!
  (syntax-rules (if cond)
    [(_ (if test a b) v)
     (if test
         (st! a v)
         (st! b v))]
    [(_ (cond
          [test a]
          ...) v)
     (cond
       [test (st! a v)]
       ...)]
    [(_ var val)
     (set! var val)]))
```

Then

```
> (let ((x 0) (y 0))
    (st! (if (< 0 1) x y) 1)
    (display x) (newline)
    (display y) (newline))
1
0
```

Note that you need to special-case all the things you want it to walk into, and I'm also slightly unsure about the whole literal thing in `syntax-rules` (I'm really a caveman CL person, so I'm only really comfortable with a macro system made of mud and broken biscuits).

Comment: That is!, I adapted it with few modifications to guile an is working fine, thanks!! (ooops, you have duplicated the answer, you can delete the other one)

Comment: @DavidRanieri: oops, not sure how I did that!

Comment: If you're going to need a dedicated operator to set across an `if`, you might as well make a `(set-if! condition then-place else-place new-value)`.

Comment: @Kaz: well, this was a toy example to show you could do this: it's not something I'd actually want in real life I think.  In Racket however it's very easy to write a module which simply provided `st!` as `set!`, which means that anything that uses this module would then get this special magic for `set!`.

Comment: too much magic ==> opaque and unmaintainable code, and it might just be better to not be able to write such code at all. :) false economy is no elegance: the proper thing to do with the nested ifs in the example OP code is to turn them into one cond expression. /sidenote

Answer (score 2):

You can read variables in this way, because the result of reading a variable is just an ordinary value. But the variable itself is not first-class: you can't store the result of `(if (< 0 1) x y)` in a way that still allows you to write to it.